# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

Congratulations, the Graphic Design Stack Exchange has graduated and earned its own design! And with that, you now have the opportunity to setup Community Promotion Ads! We're still pretty fresh into 2014 so not much lost ground here.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- artistic blogs and websites
- useful resources and tutorials for designers of all skill levels
- examples of well-designed content
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/898).

Comment: I have ideas but no time to generate ads. Anyone is free to run with them... WhattheFont.com, Typophile.com, Kuler.com, Snook.ca (or any contrast checker), How Magazine, Print Magazine.

Comment: I'm confused...these are ads *we* create that promote *other* web sites?

Comment: @DA01 Yes. It's for the community to guide people to things that aren't from this site itself, but that would be interesting or useful to the audience that the site caters to. Basically, it's a way to make is so that rather than seeing generic ads of whatever sort, you're more likely to see things relevant to what the community uses.

Comment: Huh. I wasn't aware that SE sites did that. Is there concern that it could imply sponsorship when there is none?

Comment: It sounds strange, but IMHO the duplicate has changed: it is now [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Answer (score 16):

[image: Handpicked free fonts for graphic designers with commercial-use licenses]

Comment: Font Squirrel is a great site that provides free fonts. Their web font integration is fantastic. They are run by [Fontspring](http://www.fontspring.com/) (a for-profit company), but that doesn't get in the way of  the free resources that Font Squirrel provides

Answer (score 12):

[image: NounProject: Share, download, sell or buy icons]

Comment: Oh noes! Now all things are milk...

Answer (score 11):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Printing]

Comment: My line or work is in the printing industry. There is a lot of overlap with my job and Graphic Design, but there is also a massive range of questions that just wouldn't make sense to include within our site. I'd love for this proposal to gain some traction, and GD.SE is probably the best audience to garner support

Answer (score 11):

[image: What the font!]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Why does my color suck?]

Answer (score 3):

[image: How many designers does it take to screw in a lightbulb?]

Answer (score 2):

[image: I love typography!]

Comment: Hoping this will be ok with http://ilovetypography.com/ ILT is also the source of the typography magazine Codex.

Comment: Whether this is approved or not I think the ad needs to in some way say I Love Typography on it. Right now if it weren't for your comment I'd have no clue what its for.

Comment: part of the mystery! (besides, it is wildly risky making an ad for the Font Guru)

Comment: More seriously though I've suggested an edit that just uses the current logotype from their site.

Comment: VERY good! i was not sure what your first comment meant: but that is clearly an improvement: thank you for the time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Graphic design on Pinterest]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Communication arts]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Colorotate]

Answer (score 2):

[image: snook.ca Colour Contrast Check tool]

Comment: Turns out [Snook's "Are colours compliant?" is actually really misleading](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/63325/is-a-colour-contrast-compliant-if-it-passes-wcag-but-fails-the-earlier-w3c-test). Hmmph, will need a replacement for this...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Power of Design 2014]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Colourlovers]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Check your contrast]

Comment: This looks snazzy but I'd have thought http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html is more useful with its saturation and brightness sliders

Answer (score -1):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Design Review]

Comment: Information about the ad itself should be in the comments on the post - please leave nothing but the image in the body of the post as specified in the instructions.

Comment: @GraceNote oops. Fixed