# I don't think our community ads are working

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-ads

We currently have [three](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/898) community ads that meet the score criteria to be displayed on our site, but I have yet to actually personally see one of them. I think something might be broken...

My suspicion was raised when I checked the [ads for the recently graduated Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/907). Collectively, our ads have had 3 clicks over the course of about a month. Academia's single ad has had 700+ in about a week.

It's not difficult for me to refresh a few times to see Academia's ad for PhD Comics, but no amount of refreshing on our site will display any of our ads. Am I crazy, or does something need to be fixed?

*Side note: there are a lot of great ads submitted, **[please go vote on them](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/898/8708)**! They need 6 points to be eligible.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hookup between the community ads meta post and the main site was missing.

It is no longer missing.

Comment: @I am seeing it just under the favorite tags section on the main page - that's the location on all sites.

Comment: Short and to the point, I like it! Thanks for checking on it

Comment: @Dominic - there are two ad locations on the page. The top one doesn't seem to appear in your screenshot (ad blocker perchance?).

Comment: It's back, I probably just need to give the system a second. Sorry, and thanks for your help. :)

Comment: No prob, @Dom - glad to be of assistance. Always closing the gap between devs and designers ;)